# C# Beginner exercise with bool and DayOfWeek

Tags: c#

i tried to do the following exercise but i'm not sure if i did what was required.Could you have a look and check if my code is correct or if something is missing?

Also i'm wondering if it was needed (or how it could be done ) to use the DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek with the variable isVacation so the program can see which day we got and say if we sleep in or not. I play a bit around with it but i didn't manage to do it.

**Exercise:** The parameter weekday is true if it's a weekday, and the parameter vacation is true if we are on vacation.

We sleep in if it's not a weekday or we're on vacation.

sleepIn(false, false) -> true

sleepIn(true, false) -> false

sleepIn(false, true) -> true

`public bool CanSleepIn(bool isWeekday, bool isVacation) {}`

**My code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {  
    CanSleepIn(true, false);
    Console.WriteLine("Do we sleep in today?{0}", CanSleepIn(false, false));
    Console.WriteLine("Do we sleep in today?{0}",CanSleepIn(true,false));
    Console.WriteLine("Do we sleep in today?{0}",CanSleepIn(false,true));
    Console.WriteLine("Do we sleep in today?{0}", CanSleepIn(true, true));
    Console.ReadLine();   
  }
  public static bool CanSleepIn(bool isWeekday, bool isVacation)
  {
    if (isWeekday == false && isVacation == false)
        return true;
    else if (isWeekday == true && isVacation == false)
        return false;
    else
        return true;   
   }
```

Thanks for your help and i hope its allowed to ask such questions.

If not, just someone let me know :)

Comment: What's your program output?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a code review. It is probably more suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the `CanSleepIn` method as follows:

```
public static bool CanSleepIn(bool isWeekday, bool isVacation)
{
    return !isWeekday || isVacation;
}
```

Why? You can sleep in if it is not a weekday or you are on vacation. In mathematical sense, the `OR` is not exclusive, so the condition that it's a weekday and you are on holiday is also covered.

That being said, you can change the call to the method as follows:

```
bool isWeekend = (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
                  DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);

bool canSleepIn1 = CanSleepIn(!isWeekend, true);
bool canSleepIn2 = CanSleepIn(!isWeekend, false);
```

The `isWeekend` variable is true if the current day is a Saturday or a Sunday. We pass this in as `!isWeekend` as your method requires us to tell it whether it is a weekday, which is defined as `not weekend`.

Answer (score 1):

Just translate your English phrase into code:

> We sleep in if it's not a weekday or we're on vacation.

We can sleep means `CanSleepIn` must return true if the condition specified in the rest of the sentence is `true` "not a weekday" can be written `!isWeekday`, "or" is `||`, "on vacation" is simply `isVacation`.

so your `CanSleepIn` becomes:

```
public static bool CanSleepIn(bool isWeekday, bool isVacation)
{
    return !isWeekday || isVacation; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code the requirement:

```
return !isWeekday || isVacation;
```

But I recommend to use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, and sorry .

Comment: For posting this question here.

Comment: It's not a problem. :)